# Sort populated combo box by name

Tags: php, javascript

I have a piece of code I am working with which populates a combobox with a list of folders in a certain directory:

```
<?php
echo '<form>';
$path = "images/";
$handle = opendir($path);   
echo "<select style='width:80%' name='URL' onchange='window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value'><option value>Select Folder...</option>";     
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if (substr($file,0,1) != ".") {
    echo "<option value ='/view.php?user=".$file."'>".$file."</option>";
    }   
}
echo '</select></form>';
closedir($handle);  
?>
```

This works fine except it displays the list in a random order, is there a way which I can implement something to sort the list before producing it within the combo box?

Thanks.

Comment: Read them into an array, then sort the array before displaying the output.

Comment: Can you guide me in which I can read them into an array and still be able to use the arrays in the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if (substr($file,0,1) != ".") {
        $tmparray[] = $file;
    }   
}
sort($tmparray);
foreach($tmparray as $file)
    echo "<option value ='/view.php?user=".$file."'>".$file."</option>";
```

Comment: Instead of `$tmparray = $file;` try `$tmparray[] = $file;`

Comment: @AshKing i forgot a litle thing. Try now. Thanks Anigel